# Is it possible to make physics respond to the effective mesh after a displacement material has been applied?

Tags: mesh, physics, rigid-body-simulation

So let's say I have a procedurally heightmapped plane (texture -> displacement -> material output) and use the Cycles-exclusive "Bump and displacement" option. Is it possible to have rigid body physics respond to this as if it were the mesh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that isn't possible - the 'Bump and Displacement' option (by connecting the 'Displacement' socket on the Material Output node) operates on the rendered result only - simulations cannot access the displaced geometry.

In order for smulations such as Rigid Body physics to be able to take account of displacement you need to use a Displacement *modifier* and set the rigid body collision settings set to enable 'Deforming' (by setting the 'Mesh' shape Source to 'Final' (All modifiers)).

Comment: Is it possible to have a procedural displacement modifier? That is, controlling a noise texture's roughness and scale etc.?

Comment: @schuelermine I don't believe that's possible, unless you first bake the displacement into an image sequence and then use that in the texture. I'm currently investigating this for a potential answer to a different question.